# How to prove this vector identity $\nabla \cdot \Big( ({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ){\bf u}+ \dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \cdot {\bf u}){\bf u}\Big) $?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, curl

While I was studying on analysis of the NSE and MHD problem, I encountered the following identity.

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \cdot \Big(({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ){\bf u}+ \dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \cdot {\bf u}){\bf u})\Big)=Q({\bf u},{\bf u})-\dfrac{1}{2} {\bf u} \cdot \nabla (\nabla \cdot {\bf u})+\dfrac{1}{2}|\nabla \cdot {\bf u}|^2,  \hspace{2cm}(1)
\end{eqnarray}
where $$Q({\bf u},{\bf u}):=\nabla {\bf u}: (\nabla {\bf u})^T=\sum_{i,j} \dfrac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\dfrac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}, \quad d=2,3.$$
I need to generalize the previous identity as

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \cdot \Big(({\bf u}\cdot\nabla) {\bf v}+ \dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \cdot {\bf u}){\bf v})\Big)&=&Q({\bf u},{\bf v})+C_1{\bf u} \cdot \nabla (\nabla \cdot {\bf v})\nonumber\\&&+C_2{\bf v} \cdot \nabla (\nabla \cdot {\bf u})+C_3(\nabla \cdot {\bf u})  (\nabla \cdot {\bf v}),\hspace{2.5cm} (2)
\end{eqnarray}
where $C_1, C_2, C_3$ are unknown coefficients. I need to find them. I believe that, if I can prove the equation (1), I can get the equation (2) in a similar way. Hence, first I tried to prove the equation (1).

**My attempt at a solution:**
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \cdot \Big(({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ){\bf u}+ \dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \cdot {\bf u}){\bf u})\Big)=\nabla \cdot \Big(({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ){\bf u}\Big)+ \nabla \cdot \Big(\dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \cdot {\bf u}){\bf u})\Big). \hspace{2.5cm} (3)
\end{eqnarray}
By using
$\nabla \cdot \Big(\psi {\bf u}\Big)=\psi \nabla \cdot {\bf u} +(\nabla \psi)\cdot {\bf u}$, the first term on the right hand side of (3) can be organized as
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \cdot \Big(({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ){\bf u}\Big)= ({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ) \nabla \cdot {\bf u} +\Big(\nabla ({\bf u}\cdot\nabla )\Big)\cdot {\bf u}  \qquad \qquad \quad 
\end{eqnarray}
Utilizing $\nabla ({\bf u}\cdot\nabla )=\nabla (\nabla \cdot {\bf u} )$ and $\nabla (\nabla \cdot {\bf u} )=\nabla \times (\nabla \times {\bf u} )+\Delta {\bf u}$, we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \cdot \Big(({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ){\bf u}\Big)= ({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ) \nabla \cdot {\bf u} +\nabla \times (\nabla \times {\bf u} )\cdot{\bf u} +\Delta {\bf u} \cdot {\bf u}\hspace{3.5cm} (4)
\end{eqnarray}

In a similar manner, the second term on the right-hand side of (3) can be written as
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \cdot \Big(\dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \cdot {\bf u}){\bf u})\Big)&=&\dfrac{1}{2} (\nabla \cdot {\bf u}) \nabla \cdot {\bf u} +\dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla (\nabla \cdot {\bf u}))\cdot {\bf u} \nonumber\\
&=&\dfrac{1}{2} |\nabla \cdot {\bf u})|^2 +\dfrac{1}{2}\nabla \times (\nabla \times {\bf u} )\cdot {\bf u} +\dfrac{1}{2}\Delta {\bf u}\cdot {\bf u} \hspace{3cm}(5)
\end{eqnarray}
Inserting (4) and (5) into (3) produces

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \cdot \Big(({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ){\bf u}+ \dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \cdot {\bf u}){\bf u})\Big)&=& ({\bf u}\cdot\nabla ) \nabla \cdot {\bf u} +\nabla \times (\nabla \times {\bf u} )\cdot{\bf u} +\Delta {\bf u} \cdot {\bf u}\nonumber\\
&&+\dfrac{1}{2} |\nabla \cdot {\bf u})|^2 +\dfrac{1}{2}\nabla \times (\nabla \times {\bf u} )\cdot {\bf u} +\dfrac{1}{2}\Delta {\bf u}\cdot {\bf u}
\end{eqnarray}

I'm stuck here. How can I continue?

Comment: Is the first term on the right of eq. (1) meant to be $\partial_j(u_k \partial_k u_j)$? Or $(\partial_ju_k)(\partial_ku_j)$? Or something else?

Comment: It means $(\partial_j u_k)(\partial_k u_j)$

Comment: Writing out eq. (1) in index notation, after cancelling terms, I find that $2 u_j (\partial_j \partial_k u_k)=0$. So it appears the equation does not hold in general. *I could have made a mistake*, but are you certain this equation holds in general?

Comment: I found this equation without proof in the thesis (page 85, last line)  http://d-scholarship.pitt.edu/36085/7/Thesis_HaiyunZhao_Final.pdf

Comment: You can determine $C_2$ by setting $v$ to constant, other coefficients can be determined by assuming to simple fields, e.g. $x$, $xy$, etc.

Comment: Using $u=x^2 \hat{x}$, I find LHS $\neq$ RHS of eq. (1). It works if the first term on RHS and LHS are multiplied by $(-1)$.

Comment: You are right @Sal. There are sign mistakes. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sal says the identity may need a sign change for the first term on each side, so I'll prove that modified version. (I'll delete this answer if it becomes clear the real issue isn't those signs, but they would fix it.) [Summing over repeated indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) (all but the leftmost denoting a derivative), the left-hand side is$$(-u_ju_{ij}+\tfrac12u_{jj}u_i)_i=-u_{ji}u_{ij}-u_ju_{iji}+\tfrac12u_{jji}u_i+\tfrac12u_{jj}u_{ii},$$while the right-hand side is$$-u_{ij}u_{ji}-\tfrac12u_iu_{jji}+\tfrac12u_{ii}u_{jj},$$so left minus right is$$-u_ju_{iji}+u_{jji}u_i.$$But $u_{jji}u_i=u_{iij}u_j=u_{iji}u_j$, first by relabelling, then commuting derivatives.

Comment: You are right @J.G. There are sign mistakes. Thank you for your efforts